# Why is material icons CSS a higher priority than my Tailwind CSS only in my Vercel deployment?

Tags: material-ui, tailwind-css, vercel

In local dev, everything is great because my Tailwind CSS is taking priority on styling my icons:

[image]

However, once I've deployed my app (Vite on Vercel), for some reason the Material Icons style takes priority:

[image]

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png+xml" href="/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Come on now!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
    <script>
      WebFont.load({
        google: {
          families: ['Roboto:400,700', 'Material+Icons']
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think I could probably apply `!important` to my Tailwind config but that's clearly not the right answer.